# current updated row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have 2 tables table A and table B
Table A :

```
col1   col2   col3  col4   col5
 1       A       1     0     N/A
```

and similarly table B I want to replicate table A into table B i wrote a trigger for it
TRIGGER FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_data()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE
nos integer;
a integer;
b integer;
c integer;
d integer;
e text;

select max(col1) INTO nos from "A"; 

select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 into a,b,c,d,e from A where col1=nos;

INSERT INTO "B" VALUES(a,b,c,d,e)


RETURN NULL;
END
```

the problem is 
1) after couple of secs col3,col4,col5 values are updated after 3-4 secs
2) the col1 values are continuously increasing so I cant use max() is there any other way to select the particular row which is being updated.
Also I cant use max() because in between updating the col3-5 in table A there is a new entry in table A the trigger can not give the desired output

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But you don't need a select at all: `insert into "B" (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) values (new.col1, new.col2, new.col3, new.col4, new.col5)`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

See the below example,

```
create table a (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int,col5 int);


create table b (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int,col5 int);
```

for the test purpose insert some values into table `a`

```
insert into a select 11,21,31,41,51
```

now table `a` have one row while table `b` is empty, now create a trigger like below

```
create or replace function a_to_b()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
begin
insert into b (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) values (new.col1, new.col2, new.col3, new.col4, new.col5);
RETURN NULL;
end
$$
language plpgsql
```

and assign the trigger to table `a`

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_data
  AFTER insert -- or update
  ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE a_to_b();
```

again insert values into table `a`

```
insert into a select 1,2,3,4,5
```

now check both tables

```
select * from a;
select * from b
```

Comment: table A is continuously increasing so i wont get all the values also what about the changed data after the update of table A

Comment: how table `a` inserts ??

Comment: @DominicPretto: `insert into a ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't get what OP said, any idea?

Comment: Thanks Everyone but we handled it on the java side. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to do this but finally used the synchronize method in java. It worked. thanks all

Comment: "*used the synchronize method in Java*" makes no sense (at least to me). `synchronized` is not a method. And I fail to see how that would insert data into the database.